how to use useSelector and its mapdispatch equivalent
I am figuring out how to convert connect code to useSelector in redux.
What is the equivalent of mapDispatchProps in useSelector api?
How would you convert the two following codes to useSelector api?


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ currentUser: state.user, });

const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ fetchUser, fetchUserPosts }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(main);





import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { auth } from '../../firebaseConfig'

import { fetchUserPosts } from '../../redux/actions/index.js'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function Profile(props) {
  const { currentUser, posts } = props;
  console.log({ currentUser, posts });
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Profile</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  posts: store.userState.posts,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);




import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";

import { fetchUserPosts } from "../../redux/actions/index.js";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function Profile(props) {
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.userState.currentUser);
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.userState.posts);
  // if you need dispatch in a component
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Profile</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

